# is doing a commit at the end of a line of code a good thing?

Tags: .net-core, transactions, commit

I have code like this, where the commit is done at the end of the line. the goal is that when an error occurs while sending an email, then the commit will not be performed but will rollback. is something like this a good thing? or is there a better way than the one I'm currently implementing?

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterAccount register)
    {                           
        MyAccount myAccount = new();
        using var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
        bool afterRegister = false;
        try
        {
            //code for check account                    
        
            //code for set value register account
        
             afterRegister = true;
             _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
            transaction.CreateSavepoint("register");
        
             _dbContext.MyAccounts.Add(myAccount);
             await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        
            _dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();
        
            //code for send email
        
            transaction.Commit();
        
            return RedirectToAction("RegisterConfirm", "Account", new { emailConfirm = myAccount.Email });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            if (afterRegister)
            {
                transaction.RollbackToSavepoint("register");
            }
        
             return View();
        }
    }
```

thank you for answering my question. good luck always

Comment: Does that even work, committing after closing the connection?

Comment: for now work there are no obstacles.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Ardians.sh i don't know how the adapter works, but it's strange that you're starting a transaction before starting a connection and close the connection before commiting the transaction since both actions should require an open connection.

Comment: @Ardians.sh so if the note under [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions#combining-several-operations-into-one-transaction-within-the-same-context) is correct `BeginTransaction` will already open a connection, so the lines: `_dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();` and `_dbContext.Database.CloseConnection();` are useless

Comment: and it's rather unusual someone actually wants to continue a transaction from a savepoint unless it's complex task. i can not imagine that to be the case with an account registration, is there a reason to not rollback the entire transaction?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio the purpose of why I commit at the end is when there is an error when sending an email, then the register data will be deleted so that the user can re-register. because I was just learning, I thought it was like that. is there any advice on this?